# Fast lightweight method to draw in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, draw, timeline

I need some kind of timeline in a "datagrid" and the character has quite a few lines.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/idz0zuk8u3jla11/img.PNG?m]

The left side of my datagrid works very well because there is only text.

The right side is a little bit laggy.

Actually, I have my DataGridTemplateColumn at the first index of the timeline part.

My DataGridTemplateColumn uses my UserControl as DataTemplate, where I have drawn my lines/rectangles for the entire line. This works because I set the left margin of the objects as example 500 so it appears over the other columns at the right side...

The usercontrol is a simple grid where I have placed my rectangles dynamically.

Other columns are also DataGridTemplateColumn but they are empty.

Now, my idea is to make only a single column where I can place a large usercontrol and that draws the timeline for the line.

What is the best practice to do that?

thanks

Comment: Hello, sorry for a slightly off-topic question but how do you draw all this stuff on a DataGrid? Do you create a canvas on top of it or use OnRender() or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that you want to make a Time Line, that is great. I think that maybe a Grid is not the best panel for doing this. I think that for this case you should to implement your own custom panel. Making a custom panel is great, because you may to set how the items will be showed and also you may add animations or drag behaviors.  You can see this pages :

- [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753321%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Panels Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754152%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Drag Animated Panel](https://github.com/rulyotano/wpf-drag-animated-panel) (This is a panel developed by my, you can see that with panels you can add wondeful behaviors to items, the only you need is a good idea)
- [Animated WPF Panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels)
- [Top 10 panels](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/top-10-custom-panels/)
- [WPF Tutorial : Layout-Panels-Containers & Layout Transformation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans)

Also I attached some panel links that I have found, take a look, maybe you can find useful things.

**EDIT**

---

Another thing I forgot, you can set in any ItemsControl the property ItemsPanel, in this way you can use your panel with any items source, you can use it for instance in a ListBox.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. 
But i will stay on the datagrid because i don't have to handle the scroll synchronisation. is's hard to implement with two controls because the rows have different heights.

Now i changed the code so i draw each line by myself in the overritten function OnRender. The datagrid contains one single column for the timeline part. 
it works very well.

Thank you again

Here is my result:

http://s1.directupload.net/images/130315/i5edursc.png

Comment: Though arguably a fine answer at the time of writing, the first two links no longer work.  Consider updating it.